# Algorithm for grouping similar words (or short phrases)

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, data-cleaning

I am looking for an algorithm which would help me classify/group similar words (e.g., "Amazon.com" is similar to "Amazon" or "Amz" or "Amzon"). Levenshtein is a commonly suggested algorithm to use, but there are others like Jaro Winkler and such (for example, [this is the Python library](https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html) with a few word similarity metrics)

I'm wondering if those, who have done similar word aggregation/grouping, might have more effective suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this. I used Levenshtein with a lot of heuristics.

You should really look at the data and try to figure out what works best for you. Jaro Winkler works well for names. If you try to use it for md5 ids you're going to have a bad time.
If your strings are naturally very close to each other both approaches might not have insufficient granularity to help you, or you might need some more information from external sources.

In conclusion, try to setup some sandbox environment and try running different algorithms through the data and see which one works better. You can also look at the mistakes each algorithm makes and see if a) you can live with it or b) you can fix it easily.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Luckily, I don't have to deal with md5 ids. :) The names are mostly company names with lots of variation (the data entry folks typed in different variations of the same name because they are given a textbox to enter freely). If you have time, could you given a couple of examples of heuristics that you found to be useful? Thank you!

Comment: Look at your data! One thing that worked for me was some idea of how likely each entry is. I'd guess bigger companies would occur more often in your data set, so given similar distances I would bias towards the bigger company. Another one was to look for common error patterns. For company names I would guess folk forget "the", "inc.", "srl." and other things often. Distances will penalize them a lot, so I would add special rules for them (i.e. always remove "the" and "inc" with low penalty).  These heuristics had the biggest impact for my work.

Comment: Thanks so much! Removing common words like "the" and "inc" is a great tip. I will certainly follow your suggestion. :)